# Python - Create a new DF column by copying - partial string match from existing column values

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 50k records with one of the column value like below.

DF\n

```
Index.       COLUMN\n

0.       ABC-1M-Deliveryorder
1.       KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y
2.       DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN
3.       KGFABC
4.       ABC-3Y-ORDER
```

I am looking for key words - `3Y`, `3M`, `2Y` and `1Y` from `COLUMN` and if found the values need to be copied to a new DF column name `TENOR` with `3Y`,`3M`,`1M` etc.
In case not found it can show `FALSE` or `NAN`

I tried with below code

```
df['Tenor'] = ""\n

df['Tenor'] = df.column.apply(lambda x: x in ['3Y','3M,'1Y','1M']
```

This returns as `FALSE` in all rows for the new column.
Can you please advise what is best way to meet my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    COLUMN = [
        'ABC-1M-Deliveryorder','KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y',
        'DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN', 'KGFABC', 'ABC-3Y-ORDER'
    ]
))

df['Tenor'] = df['COLUMN'].str.contains('3Y|3M|2Y|1Y|1M', regex=True)
```

Edit: OP asked the follow up question:

> The above code snippet is returning TRUE wherever the column finds the string 2Y, 3Y etc.. But i need the output as below Index Column NEW 0 ABC-1M-Deliveryorder 1M 1 KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y 2Y 2 DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN 1M 3 KGFABC Nan 4 ABC-3Y-ORDER 3Y

If that is the case then you may want to use a custom function and `pandas.Series.apply` like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    COLUMN = [
        'ABC-1M-Deliveryorder','KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y',
        'DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN', 'KGFABC', 'ABC-3Y-ORDER'
    ]
))

def find_substring(x):
    for y in ('3Y','3M','2Y','1Y','1M'):
        if y in x:
            return y

df['Tenor'] = df['COLUMN'].apply(find_substring)

print(df)
```

output:

```
                 COLUMN Tenor
0  ABC-1M-Deliveryorder    1M
1  KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y    2Y
2      DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN    1M
3                KGFABC  None
4          ABC-3Y-ORDER    3Y
```

[python tutor link to example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20COLUMN%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'ABC-1M-Deliveryorder','KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN',%20'KGFABC',%20'ABC-3Y-ORDER'%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%29%29%0A%0Adef%20find_substring%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20y%20in%20%28'3Y','3M','2Y','1Y','1M'%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20y%20in%20x%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20y%0A%0Adf%5B'Tenor'%5D%20%3D%20df%5B'COLUMN'%5D.apply%28find_substring%29%0A%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: The above code snippet is returning TRUE wherever the column finds the string 2Y, 3Y etc..

But i need the output as below


Index Column NEW
0 ABC-1M-Deliveryorder 1M
1 KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y 2Y
2 DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN 1M
3 KGFABC Nan
4 ABC-3Y-ORDER 3Y

Comment: @Dax2ib I updated my answer with an example of how you could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet is returning TRUE wherever the column finds the string 2Y, 3Y etc..

But i need the output as below
code output

''''

Index   Column             NEW
0   ABC-1M-Deliveryorder    1M
1   KGF-ORDERDelivery-2Y    2Y
2   DEFGHIABC1M-OPEN        1M
3   KGFABC                  Nan
4   ABC-3Y-ORDER            3Y

''''